# Sending Requests from postman to AWS ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, postman

I have my ec2 instance running a docker image and id like to test the functionality of my routes with postman, however whenever I ping the ec2 public dns, it says connection refused. I have the security group opened up for all traffic from my machine and am running the postman desktop app. The example route I'm trying to hit is

https://{IP address here}.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6000/register

and I'm sending a post request with some json in it. All of this works fine on my local machine. Please tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why https does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't use** `https:`. Instead you must use `http:` as default EC2 instance url does not support HTTPS. For valid https, the easiest way is to setup [ALB](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/) or set it [up on an instance directly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-2.html).

Comment: Ok I just changed it to http:// but I still don't have any luck. Any other tips??

Comment: @Nooby1 The you have to update your question with all relevant details. What is the app? How do you know if its even working? What about security groups? VPC setup?

Comment: @Nooby1 You haven't provided any relevant details except https. What about security groups? Netwrok ACLs?

Comment: The application is a java jar file. Its basically a full backend implemented and the routes all work properly when I run the server locally and ping them from postman on my machine. My security group on was allows all inbound traffic from my machine and I have not touched the vpc. This is simply a test application for my own learning and will not be in a production environment.

Comment: @Nooby1 Please update the question with screenshot and information. Does your app even work? Can you curl it from the instances?

Comment: What would you like a picture of? Yes, the application runs fine on my local machine.

Comment: @Nooby1 I'm talking about ec2. Did you ssh into it? Verified that it works on ec2 exactly as expected? There are no internal firewalls blocking any connections?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241595/discussion-between-nooby1-and-marcin).